# android Memory ,vector images

Tags: android, performance

I have been making a project in android and it has almost 10 classes as activities or fragments . the sizeof the apk is ~5mb , how can I reduce that . Also , I considered using android provided icons instead of png images but it looks like I would save at most 100 Kb. I don't think that would make much of a difference or would it ?

Comment: You could replace your assets with images pulled from the web as one example of space saving techniques. Have a look through all your files though, as 5MB for 10 classes seems large, unless they are thousands of lines long each.

Comment: It is small code only , thank you I will check

Comment: `10 classes as activities or fragments` this is not what affects size of the apk. Check for the libraries used, other resources,etc.